# How can I allow the user to draw freely on the screen

Tags: java, android, paint

how do I can make the user to draw somthing by touch the screen?

in what method I use?

Does I use canvs?

Thanks (:

Comment: Use canvas : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need to use the HTML `canvas` object. I recommend also looking into a graphics library to make things more simple. `Fabric.js` is a good one (http://fabricjs.com).

Here is a global drawing web app I made using `node.js`. Feel free to check it out.

http://node.paulkr.com

https://github.com/paulkr/pennitdown